# Get current route instead of route_path in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I have navigation bar, such as :

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li
  % if request.current_route_path == "somepath":
  class="current"
  % endif
  > <a href='/page1"> 1 </a></li>
  <li
  % if request.current_route_path == "another_test":
  class="current"
  %endif
  > <a href="/page2"> 2 </a> <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add some codes to test what is the current `route` so that I can decide which bar to be highlighted (`class="current"`).

I know Pyramid has a method `current_route_path` to get the path of current URL. However, I think it's better to use **route name** instead of **route path**. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Why would it be be better to match a route name? Normally, you'd generate these links, including paths, from some structure in a loop, and you mark the 'current' link there by matching against `current_route_path`. Why hardcode these links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
% if request.url == request.route_url('my_route_name')
##do stuff
%endif
```

where request.url is the current url and request.route_url('my_route_name') is the url of a named route

Answer (score 34):

What you want is to use the [`matched_route`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/urldispatch.html#matched-route).

```
if request.matched_route.name == 'my_route_name':
```